I am unable to Print Project Code in PyCharm
As statedd above, I am unable to print Project Code in pycharm. I need to print the [tag:Python code] for a project. Not the results, simply the text. For example the code in the project below.
n = list(range(0, 10))
print(n)
I have printed from other applications and I am able to print. The correct printer is selected. I have included the image from pycharm.
Pycharm Print Option
In addition, I have searched for this on stack and I only find issues with the print() function.
If anyone knows of a setting that I need to switch, I would appreciate the help.
As a workaround, I am copying the code to Notepad ++. I am expecting a simple print-out of the code blocks

Printing the code of a file works for me, I don't know why it's not for you. While editing the code, I select from the main top window File > Print... and then make sure the file is selected as you have done. Make sure your cursor is in the editor window when you go to File > Print...  option. If that doesn't do it, then highlight the text in the editor and then print, but instead use selected text to see if that works?

Hello James - Thank you. It must be something with my installation. I'll reinstall. I appreciate you responding to let me know that I was not doing anything incorrectly.
